# How much damage does Purification Nova do?

Tags: starcraft-2

The protoss have gained a new unit in their arsenal called the Disruptor.

**New Unit: Disruptor**

> A light-mechanical unit from the Robotics Facility that can use Purification Nova.
>
> Ability – Purification Nova: Once activated, the Disruptor becomes invulnerable and gains increased movement speed. After 4 seconds, the Disruptor emits a massive blast dealing AoE damage in a circle and immediately becomes vulnerable again, also losing its speed boost.

I've seen it on a few public streams now and it seems to kill anything within that damage range, however it doesn't list how much actual damage the blast does. How much damage does the blast do?

An example comparison, we know that the Yamoto Cannon of a battle cruiser does 300 damage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

145 damage. That thing costs 300 gas, so it's one giant baneling.